# Group object arrays by especific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to group objects by key `mod`. I have this array:

```js
const testArray = [
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 1, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 2, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 3, seq: 3, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'verde', peso: 5, seq: 4, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 4, seq: 5, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'green', peso: 8, seq: 6, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 9, seq: 7, mod: 'normal'}
]
```

and i expect to create a new array with this objects like this:

```js
const groupArray = [
  [
    {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 1, mod: 'normal'},
    {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 2, mod: 'normal'},
    {cor: 'yellow', peso: 9, seq: 7, mod: 'normal'}
  ],
  [
    {cor: 'yellow', peso: 4, seq: 5, mod: 'abstract'},
    {cor: 'yellow', peso: 3, seq: 3, mod: 'abstract'},
  ]
];
```

Someone could help me? I tried with `.map` anda `.filter` but does't works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you tried the filter method?

This is how you would use it to solve this problem.

```
let newArr = [
  testArray.filter((thing) => thing.mod === 'normal'),
  testArray.filter((thing) => thing.mod === 'abstract')
];
```

Comment: Sorry,i don't tell, the  mod  key is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function with `Set`, like this:

```js
const testArray = [
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 1, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 2, seq: 2, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 3, seq: 3, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'verde', peso: 5, seq: 4, mod: 'normal'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 4, seq: 5, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'green', peso: 8, seq: 6, mod: 'abstract'},
  {cor: 'yellow', peso: 9, seq: 7, mod: 'normal'}
];

var mods = [...new Set(testArray.map(x => x.mod))];

var output = [];

mods.forEach(mod => output.push(testArray.filter(item => item.mod === mod)));

console.log(output);
```